# Sudo doesn't work in MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, sudo

Since updating to Catalina I haven't been able to do sudo. I'am an admin user, but every attempt to use sudo (such as `sudo visudo` or `sudo vim /etc/sudoers`) gives me this message

```
this user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I know that apple has creating a read only volume for the system. But when I go the the data volume in the terminal I get the same message.

Comment: **Never** use `vi` to edit `sudoers`, aways use `visudo`.

Comment: To get back to the question: `sudo` should work on Catalina the same as before. What is the result of `id -a`?

Comment: I use `sudo` regularly on my macOS (10.15.4 as of a few days ago). I'll make a **guess** that you have more than one *admin user*? If so, you might try doing an `su` to the **original** admin user, and trying `sudo visudo` from that userid. If you get in that way, then give your other admin user id permission to do `sudo visudo`.

Comment: Try creating a new administrator or try booting Recovery and disabling SIP and using sudo mount -uw / . Then you can edit the sudoers file.